# Jquery datepicker hidden field date value compare with textbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, datepicker

I am currently working on JQuery Datepicker for comparison date with label and textbox. 
I have converted the label date to date format`( "dd, MMMM, yyyy")` and set the value into hidden field on code behind.
I pass the hidden field value into jquery with  `<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfdate" runat="server" />`

The logic should be :

- date of `txtShipmentDate` can't be earlier than `lblDateReceived`

The datepicker is not working with the below code.Need advice on this issue

**Code Behind VB.Net**

```
Dim datereceived As DateTime = lblDateReceived.Text
Dim format As String = "dd, MMMM, yyyy"
Dim newdate = datereceived.ToString(format)
hdfdate.Value = newdate
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtShipmentDate" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Label ID="lblDateReceived" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> 
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfdate" runat="server" /> 

<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">
 </script><link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //add on this code to make jquery work in update panel
        function pageLoad() {
            $(function () {
                $("#" + '<%=txtShipmentDate.ClientID%>').unbind();
                $("#" + '<%=txtShipmentDate.ClientID%>').datepicker({

                    dateFormat: "dd, MMMM, yyyy",
                    onClose: function () {
                        $("#" + '<%=hdfdate.ClientID%>').datepicker(
                            "change",
                            { minDate: new Date($("#" + '<%=txtShipmentDate.ClientID%>').val()) 
                 });
                                      }
             });
        } 

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show in console, what's the value for the both and see how they are getting generated?

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar, the lblDateReceived ---->" 02, July, 2015" which already pass to hidden field, and we need to validate on datepicker to display the txtShipmentDate not earlier than the 03, July, 2015.

Comment: Looks like you need to convert it to date format again. Okay. Will add a new answer.

Comment: And what's with `minDate: -180`?

Comment: I have deleted the minDate: -180.I edited the question. I want the mindate to have the value of hidden field.

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML instead of the source code?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I have added it under the ASPX. Is that sufficient?

Comment: I am unable to see it. Where have you added?

Comment: The textbox,label and hidden field code

Comment: Boss, I am asking you to add the rendered HTML **not the source code**. Add what the browser sees.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Not the screenshot bro! Just the code you see in the browser by clicking on either view source or inspect element.